# Importing modules from different folders

Tags: python, module, directory, pytest

I am following the pytest "Get Started" guide, and I just can't make it work. It seems to be something very elementary, but I just cant find it. The problem resides in importing modules from other folders, and, although I am following the official documentation, I cant make it work

Following [PyPa](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), I have assembled the following file structure:

```
(lpthw) ex47_pypa> tree
.
├── dist
│   ├── example_package_vcmota-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── example_package_vcmota-0.0.1.tar.gz
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── example_package_VCMota
│       ├── example.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_example.py

4 directories, 8 files
(lpthw) ex47_pypa> cat src/example_package_VCMota/example.py
def add_one(number):
    return number+1
(lpthw) ex47_pypa> cat tests/test_example.py
# import example
# import example_package_VCMota
# from src/example_package_VCMota import example
# from src import example_package_VCMota/example
# import src
# import importlib

# from src.example_package_VCMota.example import add_one

from ..src.example import add_one

def test_dif():
    assert add_one(2) == 9
(lpthw) ex47_pypa>
```

That seems to me as an ok implementation of everything in [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) pages, except that it does not work:

```
(lpthw) ex47_pypa> pytest
=============================================================================================== test session starts ================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.8, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /archive/MyBooks/LearnPython3TheHardWay/mypython/projects/ex47_pypa
collected 0 items / 1 error

====================================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================================
______________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_example.py ______________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/archive/MyBooks/LearnPython3TheHardWay/mypython/projects/ex47_pypa/tests/test_example.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_example.py:8: in <module>
    from example_package_VCMota.example import add_one
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example_package_VCMota'
============================================================================================= short test summary info ==============================================================================================
ERROR tests/test_example.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================================================= 1 error in 0.05s =================================================================================================
(lpthw) ex47_pypa>
```

The error is due to how I call the function add_one in example.p, and, as you may see in the test_example.py, I have tried every imaginable way of calling this function.

The only thing I know for sure is that the error has nothing to do with pytest: I have assembled another file structure:

```
teste> tree
.
├── src
│   ├── example.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_example.py

2 directories, 3 files
teste> cd tests/
tests> cat test_example.py
# import example
# import example_package_VCMota
# from src/example_package_VCMota import example
# from src import example_package_VCMota/example
# import src
# import importlib

# from src.example_package_VCMota.example import add_one

from ..src.example import add_one


def test_dif():
    assert add_one(2) == 9
tests>
```

but it still does not work:

```
tests>python test_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/archive/MyBooks/LearnPython3TheHardWay/mypython/projects/teste/tests/test_example.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..src.example import add_one
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
tests>
```

I am aware that there are multiple other ways of importing modules from other folders, as stated in [this 11 years old post from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) itself, but the dot one is surely the simplest way, and, since it is clearly stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), it should work, but I cant make it work.

Thank you all for your attention.

EDIT:

Following [Raphael's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14608129/raphael-moral-piazera), I have started to suspect of errors/problems in my python installs, and therefore assembled the following file structure inside a virtual machine running Ubuntu LTS 20:

├── source
│   ├── example.py
│   └── **init**.py
└── tests
└── test_example.py

where I have tried multiple import commands in test_example.py, such as:

```
from .source.example import add_one
from ...source.example import add_one
```

and so on, and, again, none have worked. Since I am running Gentoo in my main machine, I suspect that this test indicates that whatever is the issue, it is certainly not with my python installs.

Comment: from src.example_package_VCMota.example import add_one is the most correct for me

Comment: Maybe you crashed your system or python is in conflict . Try to reinstall or open and close your project. If you commits some archive  from pycharm and is there other programming, thats cause trouble too.